# What exactly are Azure website instance

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service, instances

Azure website clarity regarding the instances, are these instances running on multiple machine like a web server farm environment where  one client  request (session) can be server by different server in the farm.

Issue with server farm asp.net application is that we can loose session variable if that is the case, for this issue to get around we add machine key in web.config that assure client session will always be server by same server so there wont be any lose of session variable.

How does Azure instance work. doesnt it mean we can have 10 websites under same plan let ex s1  Standard.

I am hosting **asp.net webform based website** on Azure I am confused how  exactly instance work. there are lot of article on internet to create confusion.

Answer (score 2):

The thing with PaaS is that you *don't* have to care about that. If you have a *statefull* site, you can use the **ARR Affinity** setting to ensure a client gets always to the same instance:
[image]

Comment: Now of course if an instance goes down because of failure or auto-scale, things will break down ;)

Comment: ARR Affinity solves the problem to great extent but not full proof as we can still loose the session if that instance goes down and to my understanding instance is like a virtual machine. So from my side fail proof can be solution can be SQL SERVER based session. now this leads to another question what if session server goes down SQL Server clustered server or VR machine with SQL Server for that user account.

Comment: SQL Server would be one option but the prefered Azure resource to store session information is the Redis Cache. The Standard Tier offers Replication and Failover and offer 99,99% SLA. Thats probably the best you can get (there is no 100% solution).

Comment: While ARR Affinity helps with compatibility, it cannot be a final solution for an app. For one thing, you cannot enable Auto-scale as it would all come crashing down when one of the instances gets put down by auto-scale. And hardware failures happen, an instance might get killed because of that as well.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Martin Brandl's answer.

An App Service Plan can have multiple instances. These instances run all of the apps in that plan. So it is pretty much like a classic web farm. Except it is way easier to manage.

There is a better way of keeping session information in a web farm rather than relying on sticky sessions with ARR Affinity. *Put the session data in a central place*. For that you can use Azure Redis Cache or SQL Database. There are ready-made session state providers for these that you can just plug in to an ASP.NET application. That way your session state is not stored on the instances, so you don't need to care if clients hit the same server.

The problem I have with ARR Affinity, is that Azure does not guarantee your instances will remain running. A hardware failure could bring one down and you lose a part of your session data. If you use auto-scale, same thing.

Comment: I agree that Redis would be a better option to store session information.